# How to retain state of drawer in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on an app where i have 7 screens, I created separate class for drawer and on each of  7 screens i call my drawer like this

```
Scaffold(
          drawer: DrawerClass(),
```

now when i click on any drawer item the item color turns amber and navigates to next screens...  when i reach at next screen and open drawer again the drawer forgets which page was selected and amber color was gone... please tell me how can i make my app remember which menu item was selected recently before navigating...

here is listview builder inside `drawerClass()`

```
  ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: drawerMenu.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return drawerItems(
                  index,
                  context,
                  drawerMenu[index]['title'],
                  drawerMenu[index]['screen'],
                  drawerMenu[index]['isHighlighted']
                      ? Colors.amber
                      : Colors.white,
                );
              },
            ),
```

and here is `drawerItems()` method

```
  drawerItems(
      int index, BuildContext context, String title, path, Color color) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 0.0, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {
              //final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;

              for (int i = 0; i < drawerMenu.length; i++) {
                setState(() {
                  if (index == i) {
                

                    drawerMenu[index]['isHighlighted'] = true;

                
                  } else {
                    //the condition to change the highlighted item
                    drawerMenu[i]['isHighlighted'] = false;
                  }
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => path)),
                );
              }
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: color,
                    fontFamily: "Raleway Reg",
                    fontSize: 23,
                    letterSpacing: 2),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: const Divider(
              thickness: 1,
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 3,
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal widget that is producing state error?  There are many ways like storing data

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i edited my question and added the code... please check

Comment: are you using any statemangement property?

Comment: No, I'm not using any statemenagement

Comment: Once you close the drawer, call dispose method because its a separate widget.

Comment: Is it ok if I answer with riverpod?

Comment: it would be best if you do it with provider because i am using provider in other places of app

Comment: create another bool for highlighted on your provider and use it, while you are already doing, hope you can handle it.